# What are good reasons to do naked os.fork() calls in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Can you name situations in which one really needs to use `os.fork()` instead of `multiprocessing`?

***FULL DISCLOSURE:***
*When one mentions `os.fork()`, tipically gets buried in "you don't need to fork, just use `multiprocessing`" or affine answers or comments. I created this question so it can be linked in response. In fact, I'll share my own answer. But if you know a better way to tackle my example scenario, feel free to drop a line - it'd be very useful!*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a class `Simulator`. Its purpose is to do a very complicated simulation that you can advance by "chunks" (step by step, or for a certain amount of simulation time) with method `Simulator.advance(n)`. Furthermore, you can change parameters in the simulation between calls to `Simulator.advance(n)` with method `Simulator.change(parameters)`: they might be, e.g., wind speed, available resources, etc.

The two following statements, as it may very well happen, are also true:

- The simulation is computationally costly;
- For whatever reason, you have **no chance in heaven** to serialize an instance of `Simulator` mid-flight.

Now, say that you need to simulate `N` different scenarios with identical initial conditions that share a common first call to `Simulator.advance(n)`, before some parameter is changed in a different way in each scenario, and then the simulation is resumed for a brief, differentiated final part.
Since the computation is very costly, you would really like not to run the exact same first part `N` times. So what you do is run the first part, and then (leveraging the raw copy of the process memory by `os.fork()` in order not to have to serialize anything) you fork `N` times, pick a different parameter change in every child process, and then collect the final result from each.